# youtube link in bookdown

Tags: youtube, markdown, bookdown

We used this nomenclature

```
[![Open & Collaborative Science Manifesto
](https://img.youtube.com/vi/Y1X0xtB_JcY/0.jpg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1X0xtB_JcY)
```

to include videos with a preview in our markdown documents, it looks nice in normal rendering of the markdown (at least on github), but not in the html version of a book created via bookdown.

see

- [.md version](https://github.com/OpenScienceMOOC/Module-1-Open-Principles/blob/master/content_development/MAIN.md)
- [book version](https://opensciencemooc.github.io/book/)

Any solution to get a nice output in the two cases? (and I would limit the question for html outputs for now )

Comment: Which versions of `rmakrdown` and `bookdown` are you using? What's the output of `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()`? Your example works fine in a sample bookdown document.

Comment: you sure you're using the exact same markdown? looks a lot like there is a stray brace somewhere...

Comment: I updated rmarkdown and blogdown and now it works (although pandoc version is still 2.6). sorry for the trouble and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updating rmardown and blogdown did the trick.